# Retrieve external id info within specific object query

Tags: soql, subquery

I am new to Salesforce and I'm trying to figure out a SOQL query that would work easily in normal SQL.

I am retrieving specific objects (O) based on a value, but I also want to retrieve the values inside of the O fields from a specific External Id.

Here is the initial query.

```
SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Object1 WHERE externalId = 'xxxxxxxx' LIMIT 200
```

Within the results here I want to extend another external Id so that I can retrieve the name from that external Id with the results.

I've tried using Subqueries here since they are comparable to joins, but I can't seem to find any resources or documentation supporting this.

My attempt here.

```
SELECT FIELDS(ALL),(SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Object2 WHERE Id IN (Object1.externalId2) LIMIT 50) FROM Object1 WHERE externalId = 'xxxxxxxx' LIMIT 200
```

I know this isn't the syntax needed, but I wanted to make sure to see if it's possible.

Comment: What is the relationship (if any) between your two Objects? SOQL subqueries (nested query in the `SELECT` clause) and semi-joins (nested query in the `WHERE` clause) only work when the two Objects have a relationship based on the Salesforce Id (either Master-Detail or Lookup relationship). If that's what you have, and the external Ids are just used as filters, then the [documentation on Relationship Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) may help you.

Comment: @DerekF Object1 contains the Object2 Id in the data set.

Comment: but do you have a mater-detail or lookup relationship?

Comment: I believe it is a 1-1 lookup relationship.

Comment: I see what you mean! So because of the Lookup relationship I can just call the external object values within the select clause and it is picked up.